# Should I wrap the mediator call in the asp .net controller in try catch or is this better done elsewhere?

Tags: c#, .net, mediatr

In Handler, if appeal is null, I throw an exception

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Handle(CloseAppealsCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var appeal = await repository.GetAsync(request.AppealId);

        if (appeal is null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Such appeal does not exist");

        appeal.Status = Domain.Enums.Status.Closed;
        await repository.SaveAsync();
        return new StatusCodeResult(201);
    }
```

and I process it in the controller

```
        [HttpPost("CloseAppeals/AppealId")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CloseAppeal(int AppealId)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(new CloseAppealsCommand(AppealId));
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode((int)ex.StatusCode, ex.Value);
        }
    }
```

Should I do that, or is there a better way?

Comment: I would suggest not using exceptions as they should be used for situations where the system really can't continue. Your situation is more of a `404 - Not Found` than an exception. Consider making use of the [results pattern](https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/functional-error-handling-in-dotnet-with-the-result-pattern) as an alternative.

Comment: The _new style_ would be to use `Result<T>`. But like async / await it should be done all the way down. Another approach in the case of _not found_ would be to return _null_ from the handler and the controller can check the result against _null_ and either return `Ok(result)` or `NotFound()`.